# getting error "react-native-maps-directions Error on GMAPS route request Unknown error." establishing connection of to coordinates

Tags: react-native, google-maps

I am trying to establish a line between two locations in google maps using react-native. But I am getting

**Error :**

> react-native-maps-directions Error on GMAPS route request Unknown
>   error.

**React-native code :**

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = "...";
const origin = {latitude: 15.846812, longitude: 80.891340, latitudeDelta: 0.0622, longitudeDelta: 0.0421};
const destination = {latitude: 15.750875, longitude: 81.018389, latitudeDelta: 0.0622, longitudeDelta: 0.0421};

class RNMapsDirectionsExample extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      console.log('orgin' ,{origin}),
      console.log('destination', {destination}),
       <MapView initialRegion={
        {
              latitude: 15.846812, 
              longitude: 80.891340,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421}
        }>
        <MapViewDirections
              origin={origin}
              destination={destination}
              apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
        />
        </MapView>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 200,
    marginTop: 20,
    flex:1
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    flex:1
  }
});

export default RNMapsDirectionsExample;
```

Comment: Can you try to remove those two delta properties from origin and destination?

Comment: I tried by removing the two delta properties from origin and destination but it is throwing the same error "react-native-maps-directions Error on GMAPS route request Unknown error"

Comment: Can you try with some other coordinates? Sometimes this error occurs when there is no ground route between coordinates. Also can you access google developer console account that generated that API KEY and see if there are some restrictions on it?

Comment: is it only valid for ground route? What api we use if we want navigation in water?

Comment: Yes, Google Directions API is only for ground routes. I'm not sure if there is any API to use for boat navigation, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yup found the solution, u guys might be using coordinates for the places where there is no land route.
Like India to Australia.
And please set stroke width and color.

Comment: yes but how to handle this error thrown ?????